# Dropbox v2 File IDs as part of delta

Tags: java, dropbox, delta

I'd like to start using the File IDs as announced as part of the v2 API (Java). However, we are using the client.getDelta(cursor) call, and AFAICT there is no equivalent getDelta() method on the DbxClient2 class.

Is there currently a way to obtain these file id's and use the getDelta() method? If not, is that planned?

Comment: I've also noticed in another post that possibly File IDs aren't guaranteed yet?

Comment: `/files/listFolder` in v2 is the equivalent of `/delta` in v1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What smarx said above: /files/listFolder